# mvn clean install goes wrong for EMBEDDED maven runtime configuration on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

When I'm executing mvn clean install, I have got this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project toolbox-service-helper: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.3:jar failed: Maven home is set to: '/Users/paulmarcelinbejan/Develop/Personal/projects/ToolBox/EMBEDDED' which is not a directory
```

I think is related to Maven Runtime configuration on eclipse. [image]

logs:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for ToolBox 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ToolBox ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.454 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Base ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.508 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Constants .................................. SUCCESS [  0.880 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Exception .................................. SUCCESS [  0.789 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Text ................................. SUCCESS [  0.719 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Reflection ........................... SUCCESS [  0.831 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Sql ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.081 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Service Helper ............................. FAILURE [  0.352 s]
[INFO] ToolBox Test ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils IO ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Time ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Jackson .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils CSV .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils JSON ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Log .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Log .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Mapping .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Math ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils PDF .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils Validation ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Utils YAML ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ToolBox Web ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.105 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-19T15:36:42+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project toolbox-service-helper: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.3:jar failed: Maven home is set to: '/Users/paulmarcelinbejan/Develop/Personal/projects/ToolBox/EMBEDDED' which is not a directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :toolbox-service-helper
```

Any advice on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install maven then on terminal execute command:

```
mvn -v
```

the result will be similar to:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.5 (57804ffe001d7215b5e7bcb531cf83df38f93546)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.5/libexec
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.2.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

copy the "Maven home" then go to eclipse, open settings and search "maven", and click on installations:

[image]

click Add...

[image]

paste "Maven home" into Installation home
then give a name for Installation name and then click finish.

before running a mvn build, on run configurations be sure to select the new Maven runtime created

[image]